# How to use react useMutation and useNavigate to navigate to a different page after a successful post request

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, tanstackreact-query

Seems like it navigates to the page I want and within an instant redirects back to the page I made the post request.

I tried using the onSuccess option in useMutation. I also tried using mutation.isSuccess conditionally to try and navigate. If I try `navigate('/')` inside the handleClick function it navigates back to my homepage, but the changes done by the post request aren't shown.

```
import {useMutation} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import {API_URL} from "../apis/consts.js";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
export const useCreateBlogPost = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: (post) => {
            return axios.post(API_URL+'posts', post)
        },
        onSuccess: () => {
            navigate('/')
        }
    })
}
```

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import './BlogPostForm.css';
import {handleInputChange} from "../utils/handleInputChange.js";
import {Link, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import {useCreateBlogPost} from "../hooks/useCreateBlogPost.js";
import {getDate} from "../utils/getDate.js";

export const BlogPostForm = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const mutation = useCreateBlogPost();

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     if (mutation.isSuccess){
    //         navigate('/')
    //     }
    // }, [mutation.isSuccess, navigate]);

    const handleClick = () => {
        mutation.mutate({
            title: title,
            body: content,
            author: author,
            date: getDate()
        });
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Link to={"/"}>
                <h1 className={"blog-name"}>Blog Site </h1>
            </Link>
            <form className={"blog-post-form"}>
                <label className={"label-title"}>
                    Title:
                    <input type={"text"} value={title} onChange={handleInputChange(setTitle)}/>
                </label>
                <label className={"label-content"}>
                    Content:
                    <input type={"text"} value={content} onChange={handleInputChange(setContent)}/>
                </label>
                <label className={"label-author"}>
                    Author:
                    <input type={"text"} value={author} onChange={handleInputChange(setAuthor)}/>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <button
                    type={"submit"}
                    className={"blog-post-submit-btn"}
                    onClick={() => handleClick()}
                >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: So after `navigate("/")` is there something rendered/running on the `"/"` route that redirects back to the page the user was just on? Can you [edit] to clarify the issue in greater detail and provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: No There's nothing redirects it back to it. I'll edit the problem definition to be more precise. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, should have looked at your code more closely, I see an issue with the form usage. I was focused on a routing/navigation issue.

Answer (score 0):

The button is submitting the form which reloads the page, *the current page*. You'll want to prevent the default form action when submitting it.

```
export const BlogPostForm = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');

  const mutation = useCreateBlogPost();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent default form action

    mutation.mutate({
      title,
      body: content,
      author,
      date: getDate()
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/">
        <h1 className={"blog-name"}>Blog Site </h1>
      </Link>
      <form
        className={"blog-post-form"}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit} // <-- use form submit handler
      >
        <label className="label-title">
          Title:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={title}
            onChange={handleInputChange(setTitle)}
          />
        </label>
        <label className="label-content">
          Content:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={content}
            onChange={handleInputChange(setContent)}
          />
        </label>
        <label className="label-author">
          Author:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={author}
            onChange={handleInputChange(setAuthor)}
          />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="blog-post-submit-btn"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```